# how to solve '[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000021c356d9e00] moov atom not found' in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a video uploader in a kivy app using OpenCV. However, when I try to upload a video, I get the following error

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000021c356d9e00] moov atom not found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000021c356d9e00] moov atom not found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000021c356d9e00] moov atom not found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000021c356d9e00] moov atom not found
...
```

The screen becomes unresponsive during this. I edited the save() function recently and added an uploadClass() because I was getting another error.

**main.py**

```
...

class SaveDialog(Screen):
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def save(self, path, filename):

        for letter in os.path.join(path, filename):
            print(letter)

        def find(s, ch):
            return [i for i, letter in enumerate(s) if letter == ch]

        os_path_simpl = list(os.path.join(path, filename))

        for t in range(len(find(os.path.join(path, filename), '\\'))):
            os_path_simpl[find(os.path.join(path, filename), '\\')[t]] = '\\'

        class uploadClass(object):
            video = ''.join(os_path_simpl)

            def __init__(self, src=video):
                self.video_selected = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

                self.vid_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
                self.out = cv2.VideoWriter('media/testOne.mp4', self.vid_cod, 20.0, (640,480))

                self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
                self.thread.daemon = True
                self.thread.start()

            def update(self):
                while True:
                    if self.video_selected.isOpened():
                        (self.status, self.frame) = self.video_selected.read()

            def show_frame(self):
                if self.status:
                    cv2.imshow('uploading', self.frame)

                if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    self.video_selected.release()
                    self.out.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    exit(1)

            def save_frame(self):
                self.out.write(self.frame)

        rtsp_stream_link = 'media/testOne.mp4'
        upload_Class = uploadClass(rtsp_stream_link)
        while True:
            try:
                upload_Class.__init__()
                upload_Class.show_frame()
                upload_Class.save_frame()
            except AttributeError:
                pass

        sm.current = "home"

...
```

Comment: Are you certain that the video file you're trying to upload is a valid one?  That error can pop up sometimes if there are transcoding issues or if the capture device stops running suddenly.

Comment: **moov atom** is the special part of the file, which defines the timescale, duration, display characteristics of the video, as well as subatoms containing information for each track in the video. This atom may be located at the end of the file, which is why you may get the error when the file was not completely uploaded.
**if you see this error - either your file is corrupted or not uploaded completely.**

Answer (score 4):

Moov atom contains various bits of information required to play a video and the errors you are getting are saying that this information is either missing or corrupt.

This can happen, for example, when you create a video then attempt move/upload the file whilst the creation process is still running.

In your case I think you need to release the cv2.VideoWriter/cv2.VideoCapture objects prior to attempting to upload the file. i.e.

```
self.video_selected.release()
self.out.release()
```

Need to be called before the video is uploaded.